# Python : Function processing when arguments are passed and when function is appended to a variable / object

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, methods

Its a simple question that worrying me from long. Maybe I am not able to frame the question properly to get the right answer , could anyone help :-

When we use :

```
print("xyx")
```

we know print function is taking the string as an argument and processing it to produce output.

But when we use

```
var = "APPLE"
lower_var = var.lower()
```

I am unable to understand how is the function processing here in this case ?

Comment: var is a string object and it has data stored in it. So the function calls happen internally. You need to learn about Classes and Objects. It is fairly big topic. It will answer your question.

Comment: In Python, `var.lower()` is roughly equivalent to `str.lower(var)`. The object that you're calling the method on is passed as an implicit argument to the function.

Comment: When you learn to write class method, you'll notice that you always put a variable named `self` first in the parameter list. This is for the implicit argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, everything is defined as a class. That is the way the language is designed.

`str` is also a built in class and when you create a string, you create an object of the `str` class. That class has a function called `lower` and you are calling that when you say `var.lower()`

If you are using Pycharm, open up a python file and type `str`. Ctrl + click on it and it will take you to a file named `builtins.py`. Over there you would see something like this:

```
class str(object):
"""
str(object='') -> str
str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str

Create a new string object from the given object. If encoding or
errors is specified, then the object must expose a data buffer
that will be decoded using the given encoding and error handler.
Otherwise, returns the result of object.__str__() (if defined)
or repr(object).
encoding defaults to sys.getdefaultencoding().
errors defaults to 'strict'.
"""
.
.
.
def lower(self): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
    """
    S.lower() -> str
    
    Return a copy of the string S converted to lowercase.
    """
    return ""
.
.
.
```

Hope that clears the confusion for you. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Danny for your explanation, It cleared all my confusions. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of print(), you are passing the string as an argument. Whereas in the second case you are invoking the .lower() method you are passing the argument implicitly.
Remember methods are just functions but they are associated with an object type.

Comment: So based on above answers I understand that , print() is a function, whereas lower() is a method.

Since the class which contains lower, let that class be Xyz is written like below :
```
Class Xyz:
    def __init__(self):
          self.lower()
    def lower(self):
         #code of lower
```
Hence, This is happening. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes, using a variable called 'self' as a parameter allows us to use it as an implicit argument.

Answer (score 2):

`lower()` is a method of the string object. That mean you can call it only on strings. This is why you need the dot notation to invoke it. (Same with `title()` for example). The specific method does not require any arguments and can be directly called on the instance of the string class you are working on, at any time.

`print()` is a function which does not require any object to be called upon. It can be used directly in your codebase.